# Received fatal alert: handshake_failure when calling from Java 1.8.0_162 to Java 1.6.0_45-b06

Tags: java, ssl, java-8, java-6, jsse

I'm trying to make a https call from a machine running Java 1.8.0_162 to another one running Java 1.6.0_45-b06.
The one running 1.6.0_45-b06 has the `bcprov-jdk15to18-1.68` and `bctls-jdk15to18-1.68` installed so it can talk TLSv1.2.

However, when trying to make the https call from the one running 1.8 to the one with 1.6 I'm getting the handshake_failure exception.

I tried adding the UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8 to the machine running 1.8 but to no avail and added `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1` to the Java server running on 1.8, again with no success.

The caller is built as below:

```
SSLContextBuilder sslBuilder = new SSLContextBuilder();
sslBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustAllStrategy());
sslBuilder.useTLS();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(SSLContexts.createDefault(), new String[] { "TLSv1.2" }, null,SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

return HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).setHostnameVerifier(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER).build();
```

This is the error I'm getting on the receiving side (Java 1.6):

```
Server raised fatal(2) handshake_failure(40) alert: Failed to read record
org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: handshake_failure(40)
        at org.bouncycastle.tls.AbstractTlsServer.getSelectedCipherSuite(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTlsServer.getSelectedCipherSuite(Unknown Source)
```

Below is the verbose stacktrace on the caller side.

````
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1650550785 bytes = { 44, 152, 122, 205, 154, 11, 197, 160, 136, 107, 117, 135, 119, 57, 23, 170, 16, 220, 69, 195, 126, 196, 0, 173, 45, 128, 223, 148 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION__SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension extended_master_secret
***
default task-3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 207
default task-3, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
default task-3, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
default task-3, called closeSocket()
default task-3, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure```
````

Comment: Is the certificate self signed?

Comment: Yes. I managed to get over it by upgrading on the caller's side to Java 1.8 u271, setting the crypto.policy=unlimited in java.security and at the same time importing the receiver's certificate (self-signed) into the cacerts of the new Java 1.8 u271.

Thanks for the pointer @pringi.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get over it by upgrading on the caller's side to Java 1.8 u271, setting the crypto.policy=unlimited in java.security and at the same time importing the receiver's certificate (self-signed) into the cacerts of the new Java 1.8 u271. Thanks for the pointer @pringi.